# android listview of IOSCHED 2013 application

Tags: android, iosched

I'm trying to use the same component  that I see in **IOSCHED 2013 application** ,it's like a listview but it's start from bottom!!.
could be a listview with drag/drop option from bottom ??
here is the picture which I took from here: 
[image: is it a listview????]

[IOsched application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.iosched)

thanks and any help is appreciated.

Comment: i don't understand `start from bottom` could you elaborate?

Comment: ok sorry for the confusion.
I mean a listview which stack from the bottom and could be dropped and dragged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project page for this project can be found here : 
https://code.google.com/p/iosched/

And getting your hands on the source is as easy as doing a :

`git clone https://code.google.com/p/iosched/`

Hope this helps you!